# SMTP Flat File losing formatting in email

Tags: mainframe

I have a report in a flat file FB 133 , I'm using IEBGENER and | SYSUT2   DD  SYSOUT=(B,SMTP) | to email to OUTLOOK client. There are 8 columns in the report and they all line up correctly in the flat file. Two of the columns contain variable length data but in the flat file they are treated as fixed using spaces as filler. When Outlook formats file most of the spaces are lost and the report is no longer formatted correctly. I've tried diffrent content types but nothing seems to be working (last one was MIME-VERSION: 1.0 Content-type: multipart/mixed;)

Comment: On the mainframe you have a fixed sized character-set, when it gets to outlook it is probably being displayed using a variable sized character-set. So set the character-set to a fixed sized characterset

Comment: Sometimes it helps to format the email in HTML instead of sending plain text. This way, you can wrap your table in HTML tags that ensure it is displayed correctly by the email client without having to change fonts. Also, it's not too difficult to convert simple text into a PDF, and then mail that as an attachment. Either way gives you control over the formatting, and in my opinion, both look much more professional than simple text.